# Is there an equivalent of EVUS for non-Chinese tourist visitors to US

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I will fly to US soon with B1 tourist visa. I wonder if I need to fill out any online form prior to my trip and entrance to US. I know that Chinese people are supposed to fill out a from in Electronic Visa Update System (EVUS). Is there a similar requirement for other tourist visitors who are not a citizen of China?

Comment: I think citizens of India might, but I'm pretty sure no one else do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FAQ on the CBP website](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/electronic-visa-update-system-evus/frequently-asked-questions):

> **Do other countries have this requirement?**
>
> This requirement is new. The U.S. Government expects that this
>   requirement may be applied to additional countries in the future.

So the answer is **no**, it's only for Chinese citizens for now.